# How can I center an animation so it goes from the middle?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

An example of what I want (the main text eg. subscribe): https://sounddrout.com/

My code basically has a repeating typewriter effect on it and it just goes from right to left. Although I want it to do so but in a centered fashion (Check the website linked as an example). I want it to come out from the middle so its equal on both sides and expands out. Think like the center thing in google docs.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

/*Text*/

.font {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', monospace;
}

.mid {
  text-align: center;
}

.txtsize {
  font-size: 40px;
}

h1 {
  width: max-content;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 40px;
  display: grid;
}

.textbody {
  margin: 120px;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: var(--bg-color);
  font: 200;
}


/*typwriter*/

:root {
  --bg-color: hsl;
  --typewriterSpeed: 5s;
  --blinkLength: 650ms;
  --typewriterCharacters: 20;
}


/* Type Writer Effect */

h1::before,
h1::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

h1::before {
  background: white;
  animation: typewriter var(--typewriterSpeed) steps(20) infinite;
}

h1::after {
  width: 0.1em;
  background: black;
  animation: typewriter var(--typewriterSpeed) steps(20) infinite;
}

@keyframes typewriter {
  from {
    left: 0%;
  }
  45% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  65% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  85% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  to {
    left: 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="textbody">
    <h1>
      Subscribe To FuryRex09
    </h1>
  </div>

</body>
```

Any ideas?

Sorry if I wasn't very clear I had a lot of trouble explaining my issue.

P.S here's a Codepen - https://codepen.io/furyrex09/pen/bGaybOe (;

Comment: Could you put up a runnable snippet, it makes it a lot easier to help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Here's a code pen sorry i took a while to get back to you https://codepen.io/furyrex09/pen/bGaybOe

Comment: I wanna use just css but I can try some javascript too

Comment: You shouldn't have two `body` tags. Saw that you had that in your codepen. Use `section`, `div` or something else instead.

Comment: Please don't just link to a Codepen, the (relevant) "*[mcve]*" must be here on the site, in your question (not as an image, not as a link to be followed, but actually here, as text). Also, why do you have two `<body>` elements in your code? You're only allowed one. Ordinarily I'd have removed the `<body>` tags, but we don't correct code in the question because your mistakes may be the problem (even if, in this case, it probably isn't, but it won't be doing you any favours at all).

Comment: I removed some code so its only the code needed, but my problem still remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution to this:

```js
// TYPEWRITER //

const typedTextSpan = document.querySelector(".typed-text");
const cursorSpan = document.querySelector(".cursor");

const textArray = ["YouTuber", "Writer", "Designer", "Creator", "Programmer", "Gamer"]
const typingDelay = 200;
const erasingDelay = 100;
const newTextDelay = 2000;
let textArrayIndex = 0;
let charIndex = 0;

function type() {
  if(charIndex < textArray[textArrayIndex].length) {
    if(!cursorSpan.classList.contains("typing")) cursorSpan.classList.add("typing");
    typedTextSpan.textContent += textArray[textArrayIndex].charAt(charIndex);
    charIndex++;
    setTimeout(type, typingDelay);
  }
  else {
    cursorSpan.classList.remove("typing");
    setTimeout(erase, newTextDelay);
  }
}

function erase() {
  if(charIndex > 0) {
    if(!cursorSpan.classList.contains("typing")) cursorSpan.classList.add("typing");
    typedTextSpan.textContent = textArray[textArrayIndex].substring(0,charIndex-1);
    charIndex--;
    setTimeout(erase, erasingDelay)
  }
  else {
    cursorSpan.classList.remove("typing");
    textArrayIndex++;
    if(textArrayIndex>=textArray.length) textArrayIndex=0;
    setTimeout(type, typingDelay + 800);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  if(textArray.length) setTimeout(type, newTextDelay + 250);
});
```

```css
/* Text */
h1 {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.textbody {
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: var(--bg-color);
    font: 200;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
}

.typed-text {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #dd7732;
}

/* Root */

:root {
    --bg-color: hsl;
    --typewriterSpeed: 5s;
    --blinkLength: 825ms;
    --typewriterCharacters: 20;
}

/* Type Writer Effect */

.cursor {
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 3px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin-left: 0.1rem;
    animation: blink 1s infinite;
}
.cursor.typing {
    animation: none;
}

@keyframes blink {
    0% {background-color: #ccc;}
    49% {background-color: #ccc; }
    50% {background-color: transparent; }
    99% {background-color: transparent; }
    100% {background-color: #ccc; } 
}
```

```
<body>
<div class="textbody">
            <h1>
                I am a <span class="typed-text"></span><span class="cursor typing">&nbsp;</span>
            </h1>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Wasn't sure how to add a runnable code snippet. If anyone knows let me know.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use JavaScript . this we be lot easier to do .

```js
    $("#typed").typed({
        strings: ["This is first.", "This is second.", "Add any text you like here."],
        typeSpeed: 100,
        startDelay: 0,
        backSpeed: 60,
        backDelay: 2000,
        loop: true,
        cursorChar: "|",
        contentType: 'html'
    });
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans');

html, body {
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0cebeb, #20e3b2, #29ffc6);
  margin: 0;
}

.type-wrap {
  font-size: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* the above is for styling puposes only */

.typed-cursor{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    -moz-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink{
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/1.1.1/typed.min.js"></script>
<div class="type-wrap">
  <span id="typed" style="white-space:pre;" class="typed">
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I implement my JavaScript into html with the <script> tag

Comment: as i did in above code

Comment: With a cloudflare link? Can't I just do it locally?

Comment: Oh I see but I put it in and it doesn't do anything. Sorry never used JavaScript before